# Redirecting to a local html file on Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, redirect

I am doing a small python project using GAE. I have to handle three cases as shown below. The first two involve constructing html on the fly and these two work (corresponding to first two if statements). However in the third case I want to be able to serve a static html page stored locally in another folder called UI. The code below does not work for that case, I just get nothing in my browser. How can I redirect to a local index.html?

```
def get(self):
    q = self.request.get("q")
    patt = self.client_conn(q)
    #Show embedded graph url, this works
    if (patt.find("graph") != -1):
        out = out_txt1+url+out_txt2
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/html'
    # Show a different html output with text
    elif (url.find("->") != -1):
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/html'
        print url
        out = url
    #Need to redirect to specific file on disk like file:///full_path/a.html
    elif (url.find(".html") != -1):
        print "Redirecting to", url
        out = url
        self.redirect("file:///full_path/index.html")
    else:
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/html'
        out = "Error, please check your settings"
    if (url.find(".html") == -1):
        self.response.write(out)
```

Comment: You want to redirect to a file on the user's disk?

Comment: Read the gettings started using webapp2, jinja templates ans static serving here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/introduction

Comment: yes I want to just serve a static file on disk.

Comment: Not sure why I get a downvote for this. Is it answered elsewhere? The question is concise.

Comment: I've upvoted to undo the -1

Answer (score 0):

Needed to add another static_dir under handlers and html needed to be called index.html. Also this entry had to be before the default entries otherwise it wouldnt work.